# Breeze named saves do not work as expected

Tags: breeze

I tried to use the named saves as below and as explained in the release notes [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download#130), but it dosen't work and returns:

> Uncaught Error: The 'entities' parameter  is optional or it  must be an array where each element  must be an entity => breeze.debug.js:724 
>   proto.check => breeze.debug.js:724 
>   proto.saveChanges => breeze.debug.js:11150 
>   sendEmail

The function is:

```
var sendEmail = function () {
        var option = new breeze.SaveOptions({ resourceName: 'sendMail'})
        return manager.saveChanges({ saveOptions: option })
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .fail(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
            log('La email è stata invata.', saveResult, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var msg = 'Invio della email è fallito: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
            logError(msg, error);
            error.message = msg;
            throw error;
        }
    };
```

Any help appretiated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writeup in the release notes has the wrong syntax.  I will have it fixed.

The first arg to EntityManager.saveChanges is always a list of entities, or it can be null to indicate all entities. The 2nd arg is an optional SaveOptions instance. See [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges).  So your expression should be

```
  var option = new breeze.SaveOptions({ resourceName: 'sendMail'})
  return manager.saveChanges(null, option)
```

Comment: Sorry for trivial question but I'm learning. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JayTraband Going through the documentation it looks like there are also a few casing issues on SaveChanges vs saveChanges

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get someone to look into it.