# Breeze js save changes does not work if the controller method name is not `SaveChanges()`

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, breeze

Hi I  am new to `BreezeJs`

I have a post method on Controller

```
// POST api/company/post
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        [HttpPost]
        public object **SaveChanges**(JObject companyRequest)
        {
            return companyService.SaveEntity(companyRequest);
        }
```

And i have call this method in breezejs

```
manager.**saveChanges**().then(saveSucceeded).fail(saveFailed);
```

This `saveChanges()` is same name as controller method name. So it's working now!

But if i change the controller Method name `SaveChanges()` to `SaveChangesCompany()`
and change to the breeze side to  `manager.SaveChangesCompany()`

Code look like

```
// POST api/company/post
            [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
            [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
            [HttpPost]
            public object **SaveChangesCompany(JObject companyRequest)**
            {
                return companyService.SaveEntity(companyRequest);
            }
```

and the breeze side

```
**manager.saveChangesCompany(**).then(saveSucceeded).fail(saveFailed);
```

Then it's does not work. Why the `manager.saveChanges()` does work and `manager.saveChangesCompany()` does not work?

How can i do this scenario with breezejs?

Please please help me guy's!! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no physical connection between the names of the `saveChanges` method on the EntityManager and the `SaveChanges` method on the server.  Changing one does not change the other.

If you want to use a different method name on the controller, you need to specify it in the `SaveOptions` that is passed to the [saveChanges](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges) method on the entity manager:

```
var so = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: "SaveChangesCompany" });
manager.saveChanges(null, so );
```

See the [Breeze Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/saving-changes#NamedSave) for more info.

Comment: +1, Actuallu I have worked out my self from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421404/breeze-named-saves-do-not-work-as-expected

Comment: @user256103 Even though you worked it out yourself, please accept the answer since it's the right one.